# Linking buttons on android

Tags: android, button, android-activity

I cant seem to link more than one button on a page.
The page basically has a heading, and 3 buttons below that which link to 3 different topics
The code that i have tried (which i found on this site) was:

```
   package com.ICTrevisionapp;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class topicstoquiz extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.topics);}
        public void onClick(View v) {
        {
            Button clickedButton = (Button) v;
            setContentView(0);
            switch(clickedButton.getId())
            {
            case R.id.button2:
                    setContentView(R.layout.topic1);
                Intent myIntent = new Intent (v.getContext(),topicstotopicone.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                break;
            case R.id.button3:
                setContentView(R.layout.topic2);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

The case part.

I have also tried the code:

```
        Intent myIntent = new Intent (view.getContext(),topicstoquiz.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

but I can only seem to get It to link to one activity and only from one button.

Im probably doing this completely wrong, so how would I link each button on the page, to a seperate activity so I can link them to other pages. (If that makes sense)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to go "the long way" about this:

In your onCreate: 
`Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2); 

button2.setOnClickListener(yourListener);`

Then create the listener method: 
`private OnClickListener yourListener = new OnClickListener(){ 

        public void onClick(View v){ 

Intent yourIntent = new Intent(yourCurrentActivity.this, classYoureNavigatingToo.class); 

startActivity(yourIntent); 

} 

};`

So you can set up separate listeners for each button, pointing to a different class. If it helps don't forget to mark as answer!

Update:

`public class topicstoquiz extends Activity { 

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */ 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.topics); 

Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

Button button4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);

button2.setOnClickListener(button2Listener);

button3.setOnClickListener(button3Listener);

button4.setOnClickListener(button4Listener);

}`

Set up your click listeners like I showed above. You are specifing your activity in your AndroidManifest.xml correct? Post stack trace result when you get the force close please.

Comment: Im lost, which onCreate would i put this in? 

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
or 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 

would i also need to get rid of the case statement that i have in there aswell? 
thanks for the fast reply :)

Comment: The method onCreate. super.onCreate... is just the super call. You would put the first part of code I posted after your setContentView call.

Comment: Yes you would get rid of the case statement if you go about it in the way I presented. The sample nifftyRich supplied would also give you the result you are looking for.

Comment: Its slowly making sense to me now :) however to add button3 would I add   Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
  button3.setOnClickListener(topicstotopictwo); in the oncreate?
followed by another private onclicklistener under the first one? thanks for the help so far

Comment: From what I can see yes. You will add button 3 the same as you did button 2. Each listener will be their own method with a specific name for each. Let me know if you'd like me to post an example of what your activity would look like.

Comment: Yes please, as at the moment with the code i have the app keeps coming up with force close. so ive gone wrong somewhere. Could you show it with button2, button3, button4, linking to activity1, activity2, activity3. Would be much appriciated. Thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: Umm, how do i know if im specifying my activity in the manifest?

Comment: Within your <application></application> tag in your manifest, declare your activity like so: <activity android:name=".YourActivityName"></activity>

Comment: thank you very much. finally got it working the way it should, anyway to rep you or anything? thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

For multiple buttons I personally prefer a switch statement method similar to what you have done. First, impliment the OnClickListner into your activity then impliment the switch.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {...
```

then inside the activity:

```
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent i;

        switch(view.getId()) {

        case R.id.buttonOneId:

            i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity1.class);
                    startActivity(i);   
            break;

        case R.id.buttonTwoId:

            i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class);
                    startActivity(i);   
            break;
        }
    }
```

To enable that function to work with the buttons in the activity do this for each button:

```
 Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonId);
   button.setOnClickListener(this);
```

alternative, the OnClickListner can be set in-line like so:

```
   Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonId);
   button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

if using the in-line method, repeat the code for the other buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You could also user the android:onClick Attribute which you set in your xml-layout for the corresponding buttons. This eliminates the need for switch-case completely.

```
android:onClick="onClickYourFirstButton"
```

In your activity class add the onClick method

```
public void onClickYouFirstButton(View v) {
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aonClick

Answer (score 0):

```
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
myButton.setOnClickListener ( or something like that)
```